# C# - How to check if the user's input is present in the ComboBox (used Data Bound Items)

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, combobox

I used the Winform's `Data Bound` Items in my `ComboBox` to connect it to one of my tables in my `MS Access Database`.

How can I check if the user's input is existing in the `Data Source` bounded to my `ComboBox`?

Comment: I would suggest `FirstOrDefault(...)`.  Based on the predicate you provide, it will return the item or null, and you can just check for that.

Comment: If you have acces to the Combobox items, you can also use the instruction mycombo.Items.IndexOf("my_new_input"), which will return -1 if not found or the index of the list if found.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response! I know this is ridiculous but, how will I do the FirstOrDefault? I'm really sorry, I just started C# a week ago.

Comment: User provides input in some other control than combobox?

Comment: If you initialize the combobox from a data source, then search the desired item in that source instead of digging the control for the business data. If you have other problem (eg. the control does not select the active item or similar), then specify your exact problem instead of generating an XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you set combobox datasource like this

```
DataTable dt = getData();
cmbbox1.DataSource = dt;
//define DisplayMember and ValueMember
```

and then you can check like this

```
var somedata = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(p=>p["DisplayMemberFieldName"] = UserInput).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: 1.) `Where` will not work on `DataTable`
2.) Why do you assign `Displaymember` of each row and what is that btw?
3.) What is `UserInput`
4.) Why do you suppose that the source is a `DataTable` anyway? It can be any `IList` or `IListSource`